# Buscador en tabla javascript no encuentra con AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Tengo una tabla en mi template que tiene un buscador, cuando pongo los td manualmente digamos funciona sin problemas pero usando AngularJS (Angular 1) para mostrar los datos en la tabla no encuentra resultados.

```js
     <div ng-controller="usersController">
          <table class="datatable table table-striped primary" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Nivel</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in names">
          <td ng-bind="data.nombre"></td>
          <td ng-bind="data.email"></td>
          <td ng-bind="data.nivel"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En AngularJS (Angular 1) debes usar filter para buscar. Te dejo la documentacion oficial, y abajo un ejemplo que lo testee con tu código así que es de seguro que funciona.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Ejemplo:

```html
 
<input type="text" ng-model="query" placeHolder="introduce un valor">
<div ng-repeat="data in names" | filter: query>
```

Saludos

Comment: Si te sirvió ésta respuesta porfavor cierrala, sino avisa para seguir buscando, no dejes abiertas preguntas cuyas soluciones ya encontraste, saludos